# C-like structures in Python

Tags: python, struct

Is there a way to conveniently define a C-like structure in Python? I'm tired of writing stuff like:

```
class MyStruct():
    def __init__(self, field1, field2, field3):
        self.field1 = field1
        self.field2 = field2
        self.field3 = field3
```

Comment: Semi-relatedly, algebraic data types would be absolutely wonderful, but to use them well you usually need pattern matching.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this method other than it's tedious to write?

Comment: You may find dstruct useful:  https://github.com/dorkitude/dstruct

Comment: @levesque harder to re-factor without typos, harder to read at a glance while skimming code, than `MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct", "field1 field2 field3")`

Comment: well namedtuple generates a class, so what exactly is the difference?

Comment: `pandas.Series(a=42).a` should do it if your a data-scientist...

Comment: Skip to the 2018 answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45426493/703382

Comment: Your question itself has the right answer to "C-like structures in Python", or "How to create a struct in Python." After reviewing all of the answers below, I'd say that **using a class like you've done is the best way to do it.** *Using a dictionary is an alternative, and perhaps the second best way to do it*.

Comment: If you're concerned about performance (RAM/CPU), then [nothing beats a genuine tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65159938/dictionary-of-named-tuples-in-python-and-speed-ram-performance).

Comment: If one were concerned about performance and memory, then [recordclass library](https://pypi.org/project/recordclass/) can provide suitable solution to the problem.

Answer (score 579):

### *Update*: Data Classes

With the introduction of [*Data Classes*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) in **Python 3.7** we get very close.

The following example is similar to the *NamedTuple* example below, but the resulting object is **mutable** and it allows for default values.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float
    z: float = 0.0


p = Point(1.5, 2.5)

print(p)  # Point(x=1.5, y=2.5, z=0.0)
```

This plays nicely with the new [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module in case you want to use more specific type annotations.

I've been waiting desperately for this! If you ask me, *Data Classes* and the new *NamedTuple* declaration, combined with the *typing* module are a godsend!

### Improved NamedTuple declaration

Since **Python 3.6** it became quite simple and beautiful (IMHO), as long as you can live with **immutability**.

A [new way of declaring NamedTuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) was introduced, which allows for [type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) as well:

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class User(NamedTuple):
    name: str


class MyStruct(NamedTuple):
    foo: str
    bar: int
    baz: list
    qux: User


my_item = MyStruct('foo', 0, ['baz'], User('peter'))

print(my_item) # MyStruct(foo='foo', bar=0, baz=['baz'], qux=User(name='peter'))
```

Comment: The `dataclass` module is new in Python 3.7 but you can `pip install dataclasses`. It's the backport on Python 3.6. https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/#description

Comment: +1 for improved NamedTuple declaration. The old way was really unpleasant to read if you had several variables...

Comment: @Lavande May I know what breaking changes happened between 3.6 and 3.7 that you have to backport one minor version back...?

Comment: @PurpleIce It was an implementation of PEP 557, Data Classes `@dataclass` The details are here: https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/#description

Comment: this is good - except I wonder about the decision to require `import`  of dataclasses instead of just making them always available  .. all the imports for stuff that are useful enough to be part of the base would be nice to avoid the boilerplate.

Comment: Even with typed fields, you can assign any type to any variable in the class. For example, this works: `my_item = MyStruct(123, 123, 123, 123)` and every field in my_item will be an integer with value 123. And the same holds for dataclass

Comment: @foolo Python itself doesn't check your type annotations. But you can use static type checkers like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) for this. This enables type checking support in your editor as well. E.g. you can tell VSCode to use mypy.

Comment: The first example can also create an _immutable_ data class by using `@dataclass(frozen=True)`. Then you can use instances as dictionary keys, set members, etc., e.g., `{Point(1, 2): 'a location'}`.

Comment: Worth mentioning that it includes dict conversion with `asdict`. I am still looking for a way to initialize from a dict though.

Comment: I'd suggest adding KW_ONLY like this `@dataclass(kw_only=True)` to mark all fields as keyword-only

Answer (score 387):

Use a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), which was added to the [collections module](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) in the standard library in Python 2.6. It's also possible to use Raymond Hettinger's [named tuple](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261/) recipe if you need to support Python 2.4.

It's nice for your basic example, but also covers a bunch of edge cases you might run into later as well. Your fragment above would be written as:

```
from collections import namedtuple
MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct", "field1 field2 field3")
```

The newly created type can be used like this:

```
m = MyStruct("foo", "bar", "baz")
```

You can also use named arguments:

```
m = MyStruct(field1="foo", field2="bar", field3="baz")
```

Comment: ...but namedtuple is immutable. The example in the OP is mutable.

Comment: @mhowison - In my case, that's just a plus.

Comment: Nice solution. How would you loop through an array of these tuples? I would assume that fields 1-3 would have to have the same names across tuple objects.

Comment: namedtuple can have atmost four arguments so how we can map structure with more data members with corresponding namedtuple

Comment: @Kapil For which version of Python does that apply?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare knows it.

Comment: @Kapil - The second argument to namedtuple should be a list of the names of members. That list can be any length.

Comment: There is an mutable variant of namedtuple - recordclass (https://bitbucket.org/intellimath/recordclass/src/default/README.md)

Answer (score 107):

You can use a tuple for a lot of things where you would use a struct in C (something like x,y coordinates or RGB colors for example).

For everything else you can use dictionary, or a utility class like [this one](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308/):

```
>>> class Bunch:
...     def __init__(self, **kwds):
...         self.__dict__.update(kwds)
...
>>> mystruct = Bunch(field1=value1, field2=value2)
```

I think the "definitive" discussion is [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=Q0s6Vgb98CQC&lpg=PT212&dq=Python%20Cookbook%20%22Collecting%20a%20Bunch%20of%20Named%20Items%22&hl=en&pg=PT213#v=onepage&q&f=false), in the published version of the Python Cookbook.

Comment: Would a empty class just do the same?

Comment: Note if you are new to python: tuples are read-only once created, unlike C structs

Comment: @KurtLiu No, it would probably say `TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments`

Comment: This uses an object, with, internally, a dict `__dict__` (well, like all objects, except if you use `__slots__`). So why not use a dict directly? `mystruct = {'field1': value1, 'field2': value2}`. TL;DR: here you're creating an object *just for the purpose of using its internal dict* `object.__dict__`, so it would be less complex to **simply use a dict from the beginning**.

Comment: ...especially since you can just do `a = dict(foo=123, bar=456)` to make that dict if you like the function call syntax with keywords better than the regular dict syntax, and also `str()`/`repr()` are somewhat more useful than just giving the object id.

Answer (score 88):

Perhaps you are looking for Structs without constructors:

```
class Sample:
  name = ''
  average = 0.0
  values = None # list cannot be initialized here!


s1 = Sample()
s1.name = "sample 1"
s1.values = []
s1.values.append(1)
s1.values.append(2)
s1.values.append(3)

s2 = Sample()
s2.name = "sample 2"
s2.values = []
s2.values.append(4)

for v in s1.values:   # prints 1,2,3 --> OK.
  print v
print "***"
for v in s2.values:   # prints 4 --> OK.
  print v
```

Comment: What you're doing here works, technically, but it's probably not immediately apparent to many users _why_ it works.

Your declarations under `class Sample:` don't immediately do anything; they set class attributes. Those can always be accessed as e.g. `Sample.name`.

Comment: What you're _actually_ doing is adding instance properties to the objects `s1` and `s2` at runtime. Unless otherwise forbidden, you can add or modify the `name` attribute on any instance of any class at any time, whether or not the class has a `name` attribute.

Probably the biggest functional problem with doing this is that different instances of the same class will behave differently depending on whether you've set `name`. If you update `Sample.name`, any objects without an explicitly set `name` property will return the new `name`.

Comment: This is as close as it gets to a struct - short 'class' with no methods, 'fields' (class attributes, I know) with default values. As long as it's not a mutable type (dict, list), you're fine. Of course, you can hit against PEP-8 or "friendly" IDE checks like PyCharm's "class has no __init__ method".

Comment: I experimented the side effect described by Channing Moore. Not worth the economy of a few `self` keywords and a constructor line if you ask me. I'd appreciate if Jose could edit his answer to add a warning message about the risk of accidentally sharing values accross instances.

Comment: @ChanningMoore: I tried to recreate the issue you were describing, but failed. Could you present a minimal working example where the issue pops up?

Comment: So you are defining class variables, but then actually overshadowing them with instances variables, correct? Because s1.__class__.name = '' even after setting s1.name="sample1". This seems a weird way to do things. Furthermore, a typing error such as s1.nname = "test" will not raise any errors...

Comment: @gebissimo you'll see issues if you use mutable types like list, dict, set. That's what's hidden by Jose's "list cannot be initialized here" comment: you *can* initialize a list, but you're in danger of updating it. It's the same risk as using a list as a default kwarg value in a function definition. https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html

Comment: @gebissimo you're exactly right that he's shadowing the class attributes. Since I wrote that comment, I've learned about two better options: namedtuples, and protocol buffers, which behave more like C structs.

Answer (score 72):

How about a dictionary?

Something like this:

```
myStruct = {'field1': 'some val', 'field2': 'some val'}
```

Then you can use this to manipulate values:

```
print myStruct['field1']
myStruct['field2'] = 'some other values'
```

And the values don't have to be strings.  They can be pretty much any other object.

Comment: This has been my approach as well, but I feel like it's dangerous precisely because a dictionary can accept anything for a key. There won't be an error if I set myStruct["ffield"] when I meant to set myStruct["field"]. The issue might (or might not) become apparent when I'm using or re-using myStruct["field"] later. I like PabloG's approach.

Comment: Same issue exists with PabloG's. Try adding the following code to his: `pt3.w = 1
print pt3.w`  In a language with dicts, it is better to use them, especially for objects being serialized, since you can automatically use import json to save them and other serialization libraries as long as you don't have weird stuff inside of your dict. Dicts are the solution to keeping data and logic separate and are better than structs for people who don't want to write custom serialize and unserialize functions and don't want to use non-portable serializers like pickle.

Answer (score 30):

I would also like to add a solution that uses [slots](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

```
class Point:
    __slots__ = ["x", "y"]
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Definitely check the documentation for slots but a quick explanation of slots is that it is python's way of saying: "If you can lock these attributes and only these attributes into the class such that you commit that you will not add any new attributes once the class is instantiated (yes you can add new attributes to a class instance, see example below) then I will do away with the large memory allocation that allows for adding new attributes to a class instance and use just what I need for these *slotted* attributes".

Example of adding attributes to class instance (thus not using slots):

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

p1 = Point(3,5)
p1.z = 8
print(p1.z)
```

Output: 8

Example of trying to add attributes to class instance where slots was used:

```
class Point:
    __slots__ = ["x", "y"]
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

p1 = Point(3,5)
p1.z = 8
```

Output: AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'z'

This can effectively works as a struct and uses less memory than a class (like a struct would, although I have not researched exactly how much). It is recommended to use slots if you will be creating a large amount of instances of the object and do not need to add attributes. A point object is a good example of this as it is likely that one may instantiate many points to describe a dataset.

Comment: Informative about the `slots` that are new to me

Answer (score 28):

> dF: that's pretty cool... I didn't
>   know that I could access the fields in
>   a class using dict.
>
> Mark: the situations that I wish I had
>   this are precisely when I want a tuple
>   but nothing as "heavy" as a
>   dictionary.

You can access the fields of a class using a dictionary because the fields of a class, its methods and all its properties are stored internally using dicts (at least in CPython).

...Which leads us to your second comment. Believing that Python dicts are "heavy" is an extremely non-pythonistic concept. And reading such comments kills my Python Zen. That's not good.

You see, when you declare a class you are actually creating a pretty complex wrapper around a dictionary - so, if anything, you are adding more overhead than by using a simple dictionary. An overhead which, by the way, is meaningless in any case. If you are working on performance critical applications, use C or something.

Comment: #1, Cython != CPython. I think you were talking about CPython, the implementation of Python written in C, not Cython, a project to cross compile Python code into C code. I edited your answer to fix that. #2, I think when he said dicts are heavy, he was referring to the syntax. `self['member']` is 3 characters longer than `self.member`, and those characters are all relatively un-wrist-friendly.

Answer (score 25):

You can subclass the C structure that is available in the standard library. The [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) module provides a [Structure class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions). The example from the docs:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> class POINT(Structure):
...     _fields_ = [("x", c_int),
...                 ("y", c_int)]
...
>>> point = POINT(10, 20)
>>> print point.x, point.y
10 20
>>> point = POINT(y=5)
>>> print point.x, point.y
0 5
>>> POINT(1, 2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ValueError: too many initializers
>>>
>>> class RECT(Structure):
...     _fields_ = [("upperleft", POINT),
...                 ("lowerright", POINT)]
...
>>> rc = RECT(point)
>>> print rc.upperleft.x, rc.upperleft.y
0 5
>>> print rc.lowerright.x, rc.lowerright.y
0 0
>>>
```

Answer (score 19):

You can also pass the init parameters to the instance variables by position

```
# Abstract struct class       
class Struct:
    def __init__ (self, *argv, **argd):
        if len(argd):
            # Update by dictionary
            self.__dict__.update (argd)
        else:
            # Update by position
            attrs = filter (lambda x: x[0:2] != "__", dir(self))
            for n in range(len(argv)):
                setattr(self, attrs[n], argv[n])

# Specific class
class Point3dStruct (Struct):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0

pt1 = Point3dStruct()
pt1.x = 10

print pt1.x
print "-"*10

pt2 = Point3dStruct(5, 6)

print pt2.x, pt2.y
print "-"*10

pt3 = Point3dStruct (x=1, y=2, z=3)
print pt3.x, pt3.y, pt3.z
print "-"*10
```

Comment: Updating by position ignores attributes' declaration order and uses their alphabetic sorting instead. So if you change the lines order in `Point3dStruct` declaration, `Point3dStruct(5, 6)` won't work as expected. It's strange that nobody has written this in all 6 years.

Comment: Could add a Python 3 version to your awesome code? Great work! I like that you take something abstract and make it explicit with the second specific class. That should be good for error handling/catching. For Python 3, just change `print` > `print()`, and `attrs[n]` > `next(attrs)` (filter now is its own iterable object and requires `next`).

Answer (score 13):

Whenever I need an "instant data object that also behaves like a dictionary" (I *don't* think of C structs!), I think of this cute hack:

```
class Map(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Map, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

Now you can just say:

```
struct = Map(field1='foo', field2='bar', field3=42)

self.assertEquals('bar', struct.field2)
self.assertEquals(42, struct['field3'])
```

Perfectly handy for those times when you need a "data bag that's NOT a class", and for when namedtuples are incomprehensible...

Comment: I use pandas.Series(a=42) ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Some the answers here are massively elaborate. The simplest option I've found is (from: http://norvig.com/python-iaq.html):

```
class Struct:
    "A structure that can have any fields defined."
    def __init__(self, **entries): self.__dict__.update(entries)
```

Initialising:

```
>>> options = Struct(answer=42, linelen=80, font='courier')
>>> options.answer
42
```

adding more:

```
>>> options.cat = "dog"
>>> options.cat
dog
```

**edit:** Sorry didn't see this example already further down.

Comment: missing `__repr__()` method that imo is important

Comment: Agreed! Could throw that in, yes.

Answer (score 9):

You access C-Style struct in python in following way.

```
class cstruct:
    var_i = 0
    var_f = 0.0
    var_str = ""
```

## if you just want use object of cstruct

```
obj = cstruct()
obj.var_i = 50
obj.var_f = 50.00
obj.var_str = "fifty"
print "cstruct: obj i=%d f=%f s=%s" %(obj.var_i, obj.var_f, obj.var_str)
```

## if you want to create an array of objects of cstruct

```
obj_array = [cstruct() for i in range(10)]
obj_array[0].var_i = 10
obj_array[0].var_f = 10.00
obj_array[0].var_str = "ten"

#go ahead and fill rest of array instaces of struct

#print all the value
for i in range(10):
    print "cstruct: obj_array i=%d f=%f s=%s" %(obj_array[i].var_i, obj_array[i].var_f, obj_array[i].var_str)
```

Note:
instead of 'cstruct' name, please use your struct name
instead of var_i, var_f, var_str, please define your structure's member variable.

Comment: Is this any different than what is in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3761729/1877426 ?

Answer (score 7):

I don't see this answer here, so I figure I'll add it since I'm leaning Python right now and just discovered it. The [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) (Python 2 in this case) gives the following simple and effective example:

```
class Employee:
    pass

john = Employee()  # Create an empty employee record

# Fill the fields of the record
john.name = 'John Doe'
john.dept = 'computer lab'
john.salary = 1000
```

That is, an empty class object is created, then instantiated, and the fields are added dynamically.

The up-side to this is its really simple. The downside is it isn't particularly self-documenting (the intended members aren't listed anywhere in the class "definition"), and unset fields can cause problems when accessed. Those two problems can be solved by:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.name = None # or whatever
        self.dept = None
        self.salary = None
```

Now at a glance you can at least see what fields the program will be expecting.

Both are prone to typos, `john.slarly = 1000` will succeed. Still, it works.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a bit late but I made a solution using Python Meta-Classes (decorator version below too).

When `__init__` is called during run time, it grabs each of the arguments and their value and assigns them as instance variables to your class. This way you can make a struct-like class without having to assign every value manually.

My example has no error checking so it is easier to follow.

```
class MyStruct(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        names = cls.__init__.func_code.co_varnames[1:]

        self = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

        for name, value in zip(names, args):
            setattr(self , name, value)

        for name, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self , name, value)
        return self
```

Here it is in action.

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyStruct
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        pass


>>> my_instance = MyClass(1, 2, 3)
>>> my_instance.a
1
>>>
```

I [posted it on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/300psq/i_made_a_cstyle_struct_using_a_metaclass_to_save/) and [/u/matchu](http://www.reddit.com/user/matchu) posted a decorator version which is cleaner. I'd encourage you to use it unless you want to expand the metaclass version.

```
>>> def init_all_args(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapped_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        names = fn.func_code.co_varnames[1:]

        for name, value in zip(names, args):
            setattr(self, name, value)

        for name, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, name, value)

    return wrapped_init

>>> class Test(object):
    @init_all_args
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        pass


>>> a = Test(1, 2)
>>> a.a
1
>>>
```

Comment: Damnit - I spent two hours today writing up my own decorator to do this and then I found this. Anyways, posting mine because it handles default values while yours doesn't. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32448434/901641

Comment: +1 for mentioning func_code. Started digging in that direction and found lots of interesting stuff there.

Comment: This'd be nicer as a class decorator though, allowing for something like `@as_struct \n class MyStruct: \n a = somedefault \n b = somedefault` where the decorator builds the real class based on the static varnames, with default assignment if the class is instantiated with one (or more) members missing. Having to decorate a function inside the class, and needing a `pass` ends up basically being the same amount of code as a normal class.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a decorator which you can use on any method to make it so that all of the arguments passed in, or any defaults, are assigned to the instance.

```
def argumentsToAttributes(method):
    argumentNames = method.func_code.co_varnames[1:]

    # Generate a dictionary of default values:
    defaultsDict = {}
    defaults = method.func_defaults if method.func_defaults else ()
    for i, default in enumerate(defaults, start = len(argumentNames) - len(defaults)):
        defaultsDict[argumentNames[i]] = default

    def newMethod(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Use the positional arguments.
        for name, value in zip(argumentNames, args):
            setattr(self, name, value)

        # Add the key word arguments. If anything is missing, use the default.
        for name in argumentNames[len(args):]:
            setattr(self, name, kwargs.get(name, defaultsDict[name]))

        # Run whatever else the method needs to do.
        method(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return newMethod
```

A quick demonstration. Note that I use a positional argument `a`, use the default value for `b`, and a named argument `c`. I then print all 3 referencing `self`, to show that they've been properly assigned before the method is entered.

```
class A(object):
    @argumentsToAttributes
    def __init__(self, a, b = 'Invisible', c = 'Hello'):
        print(self.a)
        print(self.b)
        print(self.c)

A('Why', c = 'Nothing')
```

Note that my decorator should work with any method, not just `__init__`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution which uses a class (never instantiated) to hold data.  I like that this way involves very little typing and does not require any additional packages *etc.*

```
class myStruct:
    field1 = "one"
    field2 = "2"
```

You can add more fields later, as needed:

```
myStruct.field3 = 3
```

To get the values, the fields are accessed as usual:

```
>>> myStruct.field1
'one'
```

Comment: It kinda works but does not know how to print itself out `myStruct                                                                                                                                  
Out[5]: __main__.myStruct`

Comment: And why wouldn't you instantiate the class? What if one wants to use the same struct for different values? `s1 = myStruct; s2 = myStruct; s1.field1 = "two"` modifies `s2`. It depends on the use-case, but I think it's generally better/safer to actually instantiate the struct: `s1 myStruct(); s2 = myStruct()`

Comment: @StephenBoesch Yes, this is a very basic approach.  I use this sometimes for ad-hoc scripts because it is simple to type, but for code which needs more functionality, I would use a more full-fledged solution like data classes.

Comment: @normanius Sure, if you need to copy your "structs", you need to be more clever and I agree that instantiating can create copies for you, if needed.

Answer (score 4):

[NamedTuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) is comfortable. but there no one shares the performance and storage.

```py
from typing import NamedTuple
import guppy  # pip install guppy
import timeit


class User:
    def __init__(self, name: str, uid: int):
        self.name = name
        self.uid = uid


class UserSlot:
    __slots__ = ('name', 'uid')

    def __init__(self, name: str, uid: int):
        self.name = name
        self.uid = uid


class UserTuple(NamedTuple):
    # __slots__ = ()  # AttributeError: Cannot overwrite NamedTuple attribute __slots__
    name: str
    uid: int


def get_fn(obj, attr_name: str):
    def get():
        getattr(obj, attr_name)
    return get
```

```
if 'memory test':
    obj = [User('Carson', 1) for _ in range(1000000)]      # Cumulative: 189138883
    obj_slot = [UserSlot('Carson', 1) for _ in range(1000000)]          # 77718299  <-- winner
    obj_namedtuple = [UserTuple('Carson', 1) for _ in range(1000000)]   # 85718297
    print(guppy.hpy().heap())  # Run this function individually. 
    """
    Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0 1000000    24 112000000 34 112000000  34 dict of __main__.User
     1 1000000    24 64000000  19 176000000  53 __main__.UserTuple
     2 1000000    24 56000000  17 232000000  70 __main__.User
     3 1000000    24 56000000  17 288000000  87 __main__.UserSlot
     ...
    """

if 'performance test':
    obj = User('Carson', 1)
    obj_slot = UserSlot('Carson', 1)
    obj_tuple = UserTuple('Carson', 1)

    time_normal = min(timeit.repeat(get_fn(obj, 'name'), repeat=20))
    print(time_normal)  # 0.12550550000000005

    time_slot = min(timeit.repeat(get_fn(obj_slot, 'name'), repeat=20))
    print(time_slot)  # 0.1368690000000008

    time_tuple = min(timeit.repeat(get_fn(obj_tuple, 'name'), repeat=20))
    print(time_tuple)  # 0.16006120000000124

    print(time_tuple/time_slot)  # 1.1694481584580898  # The slot is almost 17% faster than NamedTuple on Windows. (Python 3.7.7)
```

If your `__dict__` is not using, please choose between `__slots__` (higher performance and storage) and `NamedTuple` (clear for reading and use)

*You can review this link([Usage of **slots**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots)
) to get more `__slots__` information.*

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I like this variant too. It extends [@dF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35993/3388962).

```
class struct:
    def __init__(self, *sequential, **named):
        fields = dict(zip(sequential, [None]*len(sequential)), **named)
        self.__dict__.update(fields)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)
```

It supports two modes of initialization (that can be blended):

```
# Struct with field1, field2, field3 that are initialized to None.
mystruct1 = struct("field1", "field2", "field3") 
# Struct with field1, field2, field3 that are initialized according to arguments.
mystruct2 = struct(field1=1, field2=2, field3=3)
```

Also, it prints nicer:

```
print(mystruct2)
# Prints: {'field3': 3, 'field1': 1, 'field2': 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a python package exactly for this purpose. see [cstruct2py](https://github.com/st0ky/cstruct2py/tree/dab23e4e0b6a920c3286c7b44d4e14664d50dc58)

`cstruct2py` is a pure python library for generate python classes from C code and use them to pack and unpack data. The library can parse C headres (structs, unions, enums, and arrays declarations) and emulate them in python. The generated pythonic classes can parse and pack the data.

For example:

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
} Point;

after generating pythonic class...
p = Point(x=0x1234, y=0x5678)
p.packed == "\x34\x12\x00\x00\x78\x56\x00\x00"
```

> **How to use**

First we need to generate the pythonic structs:

```
import cstruct2py
parser = cstruct2py.c2py.Parser()
parser.parse_file('examples/example.h')
```

Now we can import all names from the C code:

```
parser.update_globals(globals())
```

We can also do that directly:

```
A = parser.parse_string('struct A { int x; int y;};')
```

Using types and defines from the C code

```
a = A()
a.x = 45
print a
buf = a.packed
b = A(buf)
print b
c = A('aaaa11112222', 2)
print c
print repr(c)
```

The output will be:

```
{'x':0x2d, 'y':0x0}
{'x':0x2d, 'y':0x0}
{'x':0x31316161, 'y':0x32323131}
A('aa111122', x=0x31316161, y=0x32323131)
```

> **Clone**

For clone `cstruct2py` run:

```
git clone https://github.com/st0ky/cstruct2py.git --recursive
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick and dirty trick:

```
>>> ms = Warning()
>>> ms.foo = 123
>>> ms.bar = 'akafrit'
```

How does it works? It just re-use the builtin class `Warning` (derived from `Exception`) and use it as it was you own defined class.

The good points are that you do not need to import or define anything first, that "Warning" is a short name, and that it also makes clear you are doing something dirty which should not be used elsewhere than a small script of yours.

By the way, I tried to find something even simpler like `ms = object()` but could not (this last exemple is not working). If you have one, I am interested.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32448434/159695 does not work in Python3.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35993/159695 works in Python3.

And I extends it to add default values.

```
class myStruct:
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.x=0
        self.__dict__.update(kwds) # Must be last to accept assigned member variable.
    def __repr__(self):
        args = ['%s=%s' % (k, repr(v)) for (k,v) in vars(self).items()]
        return '%s(%s)' % ( self.__class__.__qualname__, ', '.join(args) )

a=myStruct()
b=myStruct(x=3,y='test')
c=myStruct(x='str')

>>> a
myStruct(x=0)
>>> b
myStruct(x=3, y='test')
>>> c
myStruct(x='str')
```

Comment: Well done including the `self.__class__.__qualname__` that is new to me

Answer (score 2):

The following solution to a struct is inspired by the namedtuple implementation and some of the previous answers. However, unlike the namedtuple it is mutable, in it's values, but like the c-style struct immutable in the names/attributes, which a normal class or dict isn't.

```
_class_template = """\
class {typename}:
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    fields = {field_names!r}

    for x in fields:
        setattr(self, x, None)            

    for name, value in zip(fields, args):
        setattr(self, name, value)

    for name, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, name, value)            

def __repr__(self):
    return str(vars(self))

def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if name not in {field_names!r}:
        raise KeyError("invalid name: %s" % name)
    object.__setattr__(self, name, value)            
"""

def struct(typename, field_names):

    class_definition = _class_template.format(
        typename = typename,
        field_names = field_names)

    namespace = dict(__name__='struct_%s' % typename)
    exec(class_definition, namespace)
    result = namespace[typename]
    result._source = class_definition

    return result
```

Usage:

```
Person = struct('Person', ['firstname','lastname'])
generic = Person()
michael = Person('Michael')
jones = Person(lastname = 'Jones')


In [168]: michael.middlename = 'ben'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-168-b31c393c0d67>", line 1, in <module>
michael.middlename = 'ben'

  File "<string>", line 19, in __setattr__

KeyError: 'invalid name: middlename'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a 3.7 for @dataclass and need mutability, the following code might work for you. It's quite self-documenting and IDE-friendly (auto-complete), prevents writing things twice, is easily extendable and it is very simple to test that all instance variables are completely initialized:

```
class Params():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 : int = None
        self.var2 : str = None

    def are_all_defined(self):
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            assert (value is not None), "instance variable {} is still None".format(key)
        return True


params = Params()
params.var1 = 2
params.var2 = 'hello'
assert(params.are_all_defined)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to do this was to use a custom dictionary class as explained in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14620633/8484485

If iPython autocompletion support is needed, simply define the **dir**() function like this:

```py
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
    def __dir__(self):
        return self.keys()
```

You then define your pseudo struct like so: (this one is nested)

```
my_struct=AttrDict ({
    'com1':AttrDict ({
        'inst':[0x05],
        'numbytes':2,
        'canpayload':False,
        'payload':None
    })
})
```

You can then access the values inside my_struct like this:

`print(my_struct.com1.inst)`

=>`[5]`

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way I can think of is to use a class decorator that lets you declare a static class and rewrite it to act as a struct with normal, named properties:

```py
from as_struct import struct

@struct
class Product():
    name = 'unknown product'
    quantity = -1
    sku = '-'

# create instance
p = Product('plush toy', sku='12-345-6789')

# check content:
p.name     # plush toy
p.quantity # -1 
p.sku      # 12-345-6789
```

Using the following decorator code:

```py
def struct(struct_class):
    # create a new init
    def struct_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        i = 0 # we really don't need enumerate() here...
        for value in args:
            name = member_names[i]
            default_value = member_values[i]
            setattr(self, name, value if value is not None else default_value)
            i += 1 # ...we just need to inc an int
        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            i = member_names.index(key)
            default_value = member_values[i]
            setattr(self, key, value if value is not None else default_value)
    # extract the struct members
    member_names = []
    member_values = []
    for attr_name in dir(struct_class):
        if not attr_name.startswith('_'):
            value = getattr(struct_class, attr_name)
            if not callable(value):
                member_names.append(attr_name)
                member_values.append(value)
    # rebind and return
    struct_class.init = struct_init
    return struct_class
```

Which works by taking the class, extracting the field names and their default values, then *rewriting the class's `__init__` function* to set `self` attributes based on knowing which argument index maps to which property name.

Answer (score 0):

I think Python structure dictionary is suitable for this requirement.

```py
d = dict{}
d[field1] = field1
d[field2] = field2
d[field2] = field3
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending @gz.'s (generally superior to this one) answer, for a **quick and dirty** namedtuple structure we can do:

```
import collections

x = collections.namedtuple('foobar', 'foo bar')(foo=1,bar=2)
y = collections.namedtuple('foobar', 'foo bar')(foo=3,bar=4)
print(x,y)

>foobar(foo=1, bar=2) foobar(foo=3, bar=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

##### The simplest C-struct-like, dot-accessed (`my_struct.my_var`), container in Python is an empty class

...like this:

```py
class AnyStruct():
    pass
```

> I'm tired of writing stuff like:
>
> ```py
> class MyStruct():
>     def __init__(self, field1, field2, field3):
>         self.field1 = field1
>         self.field2 = field2
>         self.field3 = field3
> ```

Technically, you don't have to write all that. The simplest class just contains `pass`. And, classes in Python are naturally C-struct-like and can have any data arbitrarily added to them at run-time. So, just do this:

```py
# Create a universal C-struct-like class
class AnyStruct():
    pass

# Make a universal print function to print all user-added members of any class 
# like this:
def print_any_class(class_instance):
    """
    Print all members of a class.
    """
    for key, value in class_instance.__dict__.items():
        print(f"{key}: {value}")
    print()

# Construct an instance of the C-struct-like class, `AnyStruct`
my_data = AnyStruct()

# Add any variables or values you want to it, at run-time
my_data.name = "Some useful name of this data"
my_data.x = 123
my_data.y = 456
my_data.z = 789.001
my_data.is_ready = True

# Print it
print_any_class(my_data)
```

Output:

```
name: Some useful name of this data
x: 123
y: 456
z: 789.001
is_ready: True
```

##### References:

1. My example program, [`struct_c_like.py`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/python/struct_c_like.py) in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo.
2. I chatted with GitHub CoPilot to aid me in learning some of the above techniques, such as iterating over dictionaries and knowing that `.__dict__` exists. All words and code above are my own, however.