# typeerror python

Tags: python

I looked into the example here [C-like structures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988/c-like-structures-in-python)

But The example is of "bunch" but anyways the code is here

```
class Bunch:
def __init__(self,  **kwds):
    self.__dict__.update(kwds)
```

BUt I am using it like this

```
p = Bunch(x,y)
```

BUt I am getting a type error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: ooh never mind.. i forgot to pu tthe value. with the filed

Comment: You defined `__init__` to not take any positional arguments (apart from `self`), only keyword arguments. But when you instantiate it, you pass two positional arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass keyword arguments. Otherwise it doesn't know the names you want to give to the attributes `x` and `y`.

Try

```
p = Bunch(x=x, y=y)
```

To amplify on this, when you see `**argname` in the arguments to a function or method, it has a very specific meaning. It means take all keyword arguments passed to the function that aren't already named and combine them together into a dict called `argname`. See below for an example.

```
>>> class Bunch(object):
...     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
...         self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
...         print kwargs
... 
>>> x, y = 5, 6
>>> p = Bunch(x=x, y=y)
{'y': 6, 'x': 5}
>>> p.x
5
>>> p.y
6
```

If you try to pass non-keyword args to a function that only accepts `**kwargs`, you'll get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for keyword arguments by using that `**` before the `**kwds` parameter for your `__init__` function.

This works:

```
p = Bunch(x=x, y=y)
```