# Can I use a class variable in python similarly to how a struct variable in C is used?

Tags: python, c

I wrote a program in C that uses structs to model the motion of planets going around the Sun.  I want to write that same program in Python.  The planets and Sun are treated as particles.

In C I wrote a struct for the data of any particle.  In the 2D arrays, the rows are the x,y,z components and the columns are the old,current,new iterations.  The acceleration of each particle doesn't change so it is an array of x,y,z components.

```
struct type_particle {
    double mass;
    double acceleration[3];
    double position[3][3];
    double velocity[3][3];
};
```

I used this struct variable to access data about specific particles.  Each element in the array is a specific particle where N=9.  For example, particle[0] is the Sun.

```
static struct type_particle particle[N];
```

I define the initial x-position of the Sun by

```
particle[0].position[0][0] = -0.002893107099833329;
```

I want to do the same thing in Python using classes.  I am just using the Sun and one planet so N=2.  So far I have this.

```
class type_particle:
    particle = [N]
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.position = [],[]
```

I am not sure if I can define the class variable "particle" as a list.  Is this on the right track to creating something that gives the same results as the struct and struct variable I used earlier?  I read that classes can be used like structs but I do not understand how.  My goal is to use a class to access data for a particular particle.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can, I don't get `self.position = [], []`? if you want a list of points, you can define a point `class` too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C-like structures in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988/c-like-structures-in-python)

Comment: Right now, `particle` is defined as a list that contains the value of `N`, which means it's a list with one element in it.

Comment: Yes, a class is like a struct with methods. But your array of structs is not part of the struct in C--why would you make it part of the class in Python? It should be a list of particle objects. The particle objects should just have the same members your struct does.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a Python [class](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html). Since your use-case is quite simple, you can use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) which essentially creates a boilerplate class for you:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Particle = namedtuple('Particle', ['mass', 'acceleration', 'position', 'velocity'])
```

Then,

```
>>> sun_mass = 1.989e30
>>> sun_acceleration = [1, 2, 3]
>>> sun_position = [4, 5, 6]
>>> sun_velocity = [7, 8, 9]
>>> sun = Particle(sun_mass, sun_acceleration, sun_position, sun_velocity)
>>> sun
Particle(mass=1.989e+30, acceleration=[1, 2, 3], position=[4, 5, 6], velocity=[7, 8, 9])
```

Inspired by iharob's answer, you can also have a `Vector` [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
Vector = namedtuple('Vector', ['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

Even if you were to create your own class for `Particle` because you want to easily to some checks etc. before initialising it, you should still use a `namedtuple` for `Vector` as it is very simple. But, be mindful that `namedtuple`s are immutable so once initialised you cannot change its attributes. For `mass`, that is fine because the mass doesn't change. But if you wanted to change the attributes on the `Vector` then you have to use a `list` instead, as shown in the first example.

Comment: I don't see the benefit in using this, what is it?

Comment: If all is needed is a simple class with some attributes, then it's simpler to write and read; I feel it's more pythonic (although you may disagree). It may not be suitable if the OP requires to do different checks etc. when instantiating an object. But, since OP was using a struct, I assumed all OP needs is a container.

Comment: @iharob as for the benefit, namedtuples use less memory because their properties are not stored in a normal dict. It's essentially the same as your answer, but with `__slots__` and some other batteries included.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for this problem. The first is to use a class;

```
struct type_particle {
    double mass;
    double acceleration[3];
    double position[3][3];
    double velocity[3][3];
};
```

becomes

```
class TypeParticle:
    def __init__(self): #pass any kind of init variable you know as an argument
        self.mass = None
        self.acceleration = []
        self.position = []
        self.velocity = []
```

However, you should - maybe - look into dictionaries (the single most useful data object in Python - I think). However, this only makes sense if the number of particles is small, for a (large) list of dictionaries is, as was commented on, not something you want. In this case, this would become

```
type_particle = {
    'mass' = 0.,
    'acceleration' = [],
    'position' = [],
    'velocity' = []
}
```

you could then access it with e.g.

```
type_particle['acceleration']
```

Some explanation: Python [duck-types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and dynamically allocates memory. Therefore you do need neither to set the types, nor the exact size of the lists.

Comment: A list of dictionaries, eh?  I'm thinking a class is definitely appropriate here.

Comment: to class or not to class ... well, that's a different debate :-)

Comment: Your proposed change to a dictionary would slow his code down tremendously. Yes, dictionaries are fabulously useful when your need them--but a huge waste of resources when you don't.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: In CPython, the attribute lookup uses a dictionary anyway.

Comment: The example with `class TypeParticle` has some serious errors in it: `self` is missing everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

See this idea

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

class Particle:
    def __init__(self, mass, acceleration, position, velocity):
        self.position = [None, position,None]
        self.velocity = [None, velocity, None]
        self.acceleration = [None, acceleration, None]
        self.mass = mass

particles    = []
position     = Vector(-0.002893107099833329, 0, 0)
velocity     = Vector(0, 0, 0) # at rest
mass         = sunMass
acceleration = initialAcceleration

particle.append(Particle(mass, acceleration, position, velocity);
.
.
.
particle.append(Particle(otherMass, otherAcceleration, otherPosition, otherVelocity);
```

you can use classes this way, and further more, you can add methods to update the values, get the values, print the etc.