# Manually pass commands into argparse? | Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, argparse

I am making a terminal game using Python's wonderful Cmd library. But i was curious if i could somehow put argparse code into it. Like use argparse to handle the 'args' from my cmd.Cmd() class.
To do this, i was really hoping that argparse had a way to manually pass args into it. I skimmed over the docs, but didn't notice anything like that.

Comment: As in [`parse_args(args)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args)?

Comment: @dhke Can i just pass strings in like that?

Comment: See the linked documentation. They use it all throughout.

Comment: @Cyanite It takes a sequence (list, tuple) of arguments like those in `sys.argv`. `parse_args()` is equal to `parse_args(sys.argv)`. If you want to pass a single shell-like string (with quoting), you might want to use [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html), first.

Comment: @dhke do i have to import `shlex`?

Comment: @Cyanite Yes, and: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @dhke works just like i wanted. If you can just add it as an answer so i can close this question. Thank you so much. ^~^

Comment: For the testing I do the simple string split on white space is enough, e.g. `'--foo 1 bar'.split()`.  `shlex.split` is needed if you have quoted strings or special characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`parse_args()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) takes an optional argument `args` with a list (or tuple) of to parse. `parse_args()` (without arguments) is equivalent to [`parse_args(sys.argv[1:])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#parsing-arguments):

> In a script, `parse_args()` will typically be called with no arguments, and the `ArgumentParser` will automatically determine the command-line arguments from `sys.argv`.

If you do not have a tuple, but a single string, shell-like argument splitting can be accomplished using [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html)

```
>>> shlex.split('"A" B C\\ D')
['A', 'B', 'C D']
```

Note that `argparse` will print usage and help messages as well as `exit()` on fatal errors. You can override `.error()` to handle errors yourself:

```
class ArgumentParserNoExit(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        raise ValueError(message) # or whatever you like
```

Comment: Side note for anyone else taking this as an answer: if you imput an invalid command (like 'help' instead of '--help') argparse will give you an error(visually) and THEN raise an error. So if you `except` the error the user will still see the error, but the script wont crash.

Comment: @Cyanite `argparse` will also `exit()` on fatal errors. Override `.error()` on the parser to fix that.

Comment: I do not understand the part about overriding the `.error()` can i not just `except SystemExit: pass`? It's a game - I don't want it to crash everytime players typo a command in `Cmd()`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [namedtuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033/13097140) to manually provide the input arguments,

```
from collections import namedtuple
ManualInput = namedtuple("ManualInput", ["arg1", "arg2"])
args = ManualInput(1, 4)
```

you will get

```
In [1]: print(args.arg2)
Out[1]: 4
```