# Python : How to express struct of C style in python?

Tags: python

I want to use struct on the python as like below C style.

```
typedef
{
  int a;
  int b;
}my_struct_t;

my_strut_t func(my_strut_t ttt, int var1, int var2)
{
  ttt.a = var1;
  ttt.b = var2;

  return ttt;
}

main()
{
  my_struct_t my_struct;

  my_struct = func(my_struct, 10, 20);

  printf("a=%d, b=%d", my_struct.a, my_struct.b);
}
```

Could you translate above C style code to python script?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C-like structures in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988/c-like-structures-in-python)

Comment: Consider using the [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) type. It was written explicitly to handle record types like this.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim that depends on the use case - because `namedtuple`s (as any `tuple` or `tuple`-like objects) are immutable. It would work for the code above, but not so much if the `my_struct` is meant to be mutated (a field's changed) somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `class` in python instead of a `struct`

```
class my_struct_t(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

def main():
    my_struct = my_struct_t(10, 20)
    print('a={}, b={}'.format(my_struct.a, my_struct.b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `class`:

```
class Struct:
    pass

# or, equivalently:

Struct = type("Struct", (), {})
```

Then you can create members of that class on the fly:

```
test = Struct()

test.a = 5 # create a new member
print(test.a)

print(test.b) # Error: this member doesn't exist
# but you can create it easily
```

Then, once you create all the members necessary *for each instance*, you can pass the instances of this class around etc.

Be aware that newly initialized instances *do not* have any members except some default ones.