# How to implement structure data type in python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

Could any one help me to implement C structure data type in python?
I need a similar structure data type in python as below.

```
struct msgbuf
{
   long mtype;
   char mtext[100];
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C-like structures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988/c-like-structures-in-python)

Comment: See if named tuples are what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python

Comment: That's what named tuples are for.

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields