# Dictionary of (named) tuples in Python and speed/RAM performance

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, namedtuple

I'm creating a dictionary `d` of one million of items which are tuples, and ideally I'd like to access  them with:

```
d[1634].id       # or  d[1634]['id']
d[1634].name     # or  d[1634]['name']
d[1634].isvalid  # or  d[1634]['isvalid']
```

rather than `d[1634][0]`, `d[1634][1]`, `d[1634][2]` which is less explicit.

According to my test:

```
import os, psutil, time, collections, typing
Tri = collections.namedtuple('Tri', 'id,name,isvalid')
Tri2 = typing.NamedTuple("Tri2", [('id', int), ('name', str), ('isvalid', bool)])
t0 = time.time()
# uncomment only one of these 4 next lines:
d = {i: (i+1, 'hello', True) for i in range(1000000)}                                 # tuple
# d = {i: {'id': i+1, 'name': 'hello', 'isvalid': True} for i in range(1000000)}      # dict
# d = {i: Tri(id=i+1, name='hello', isvalid=True) for i in range(1000000)}            # namedtuple
# d = {i: Tri2(id=i+1, name='hello', isvalid=True) for i in range(1000000)}            # NamedTuple
print('%.3f s  %.1f MB' % (time.time()-t0, psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2))

"""
tuple:       0.257 s  193.3 MB
dict:        0.329 s  363.6 MB
namedtuple:  1.253 s  193.3 MB  (collections)
NamedTuple:  1.250 s  193.5 MB  (typing)
"""
```

- using a `dict` doubles the RAM usage, compared to a `tuple`
- using a `namedtuple` or `NamedTuple` multiplies by 5 the time spent, compared to a `tuple`!

**Question: is there a tuple-like data structure in Python 3 which allows to access the data with `x.id`, `x.name`, etc. and also is RAM and CPU efficient?**

---

Notes:

- in my real use case, the `tuple` is something like a C-struct of type `(uint64, uint64, bool)`.
- I've also tried with:

  - `slots` (to avoid the interal object's `__dict__`, see [Usage of __slots__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots))
  - `dataclass`:

    ```
    @dataclasses.dataclass
    class Tri3:
        id: int
        ...
    ```
  - `ctypes.Structure`:

    ```
    class Tri7(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [("id", ctypes.c_int), ...]
    ```

  but it was not better (all of them ~ 1.2 sec.), nothing close to a genuine `tuple` in terms of performance
- Here are other options: [C-like structures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988/c-like-structures-in-python)

Comment: Unless you are frequently rebuilding the entire dictionary, I wouldn't worry too much about how long it takes to do so. In practice, you are probably going to be loading data from a file, and the IO is going to take longer than instantiating the objects.

Comment: what performance do you care about? Creation or lookup?

Comment: The `psutil` method you use gives you just a snapshot of the current memory usage. It is notoriously inaccurate in the face of garbage-collection etc.  In fact, multiple runs will show you how it fluctuates.

Comment: @anon01 both are important

Comment: two more methods to consider: a `@dataclass` (slower than your `namedtuple`), and making a larger container at once such as a `pandas.DataFrame` (also slower, but quite compact). The latter also wouldn't give you directly a dot accessor; instead you'd have to do: `df.iloc[1634].name`.

Comment: @chepner creation time is important in my application because there could be 10 millions of items a well

Comment: you may consider implementing your own container. If you use column-orientation, you are likely to save on memory.

Comment: @PierreD it does fluctuate indeed but not much: the order of magnitude is the same. The garbage collector shouldn't have cleaned `d` when the RAM usage is printed with psutil, so here it's rather accurate.

Comment: `slots` may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots/28059785#28059785

Comment: only if you place it in its own script and run that script with a new interpreter. If instead you have a notebook, for example, and run the same cell repeatedly, you'll see lots of variations. The `rss` is also the total ram consumed by the whole process, not just what used by your structure.

Comment: My suggestion however would be to use whatever is easiest until you are very confident of your performance requirements based on usage.  Unless you already *know* that you're hitting memory issues, or that object creation needs to be optimized, I would use a nested dict or pandas dataframe.

Comment: Have you already ruled out a plain database as a solution? It sounds like you are trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @chepner I'm looking for something as close as possible as a C-`struct`.

Comment: That would be a tuple. But I wouldn't suggest keeping millions of struct values in memory at once in C, either, because you would probably be better off with a database management system that *already* knows how to manage memory efficiently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cython's [cdef-classes](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html) might be what you want: They use less memory than the pure Python classes, even if it comes at costs of more overhead when accessing members (because fields are stored as C-values and not Python-objects).

For example:

```
%%cython
cdef class CTuple:
    cdef public unsigned long long int id
    cdef public str name
    cdef public bint isvalid
    
    def __init__(self, id, name, isvalid):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.isvalid = isvalid
```

which can be used as wished:

```
ob=CTuple(1,"mmm",3)
ob.id, ob.name, ob.isvalid # prints (2, "mmm", 3)
```

**Timings/memory consumption:**

First, the baseline on my machine:

```
0.258 s  252.4 MB  # tuples
0.343 s  417.5 MB  # dict
1.181 s  264.0 MB  # namedtuple collections
```

with `CTuple` we get:

```
0.306 s  191.0 MB
```

which is almost as fast and needs considerable less memory.

If the C-type of members isn't clear at compile time, one could use simple python-objects:

```
%%cython
cdef class PTuple:
    cdef public object id
    cdef public object name
    cdef public object isvalid
    
    def __init__(self, id, name, isvalid):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.isvalid = isvalid
```

The timings are a little bit surprising:

```
0.648 s  249.8 MB
```

I didn't expect it to be so much slower than the `CTuple`-version, but at least it is twice as fast as named tuples.

---

One disadvantage of this approach is that it needs compilation. Cython however offers `cython.inline` which can be used to compile Cython-code created on-the-fly.

I've released [`cynamedtuple`](https://pypi.org/project/cynamedtuple/) which can be installed via `pip install cynamedtuple`, and is based on the prototype bellow:

```
import cython

# for generation of cython code:
tab = "    "
def create_members_definition(name_to_ctype):
    members = []
    for my_name, my_ctype in name_to_ctype.items():
        members.append(tab+"cdef public "+my_ctype+" "+my_name)
    return members

def create_signature(names):
    return tab + "def __init__(self,"+", ".join(names)+"):"

def create_initialization(names):
    inits = [tab+tab+"self."+x+" = "+x for x in names]
    return inits

def create_cdef_class_code(classname, names):
    code_lines = ["cdef class " + classname + ":"]
    code_lines.extend(create_members_definition(names))
    code_lines.append(create_signature(names.keys()))
    code_lines.extend(create_initialization(names.keys()))
    return "\n".join(code_lines)+"\n"

# utilize cython.inline to generate and load pyx-module:
def create_cnamedtuple_class(classname, names):
    code = create_cdef_class_code(classname, names)
    code = code + "GenericClass = " + classname +"\n"
    ret = cython.inline(code)
    return ret["GenericClass"]
```

Which can be used as follows, to dynamically define `CTuple` from above:

```
CTuple = create_cnamedtuple_class("CTuple", 
                                 {"id":"unsigned long long int", 
                                  "name":"str",
                                  "isvalid":"bint"})

ob = CTuple(1,"mmm",3)
...
```

---

Another alternative could be to use jit-compilation and Numba's [jitted-classes](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jitclass.html) which offer this possibility. They however seem to be much slower:

```
from numba import jitclass, types

spec = [
    ('id', types.uint64), 
    ('name', types.string),
    ('isvalid',  types.uint8),
]

@jitclass(spec)
class NBTuple(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, isvalid):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.isvalid = isvalid
```

and the results are:

```
20.622 s  394.0 MB
```

so numba jitted classes are not (yet?) a good choice.

Comment: Wonderful solution @ead! Is it possible to use a once-for-all Cython-compiled version? Then I could compile this module only once, once for all, and then just do `MyCTuple = GenericCTuple(types=[ctypes.unsignedlonglongint, ctypes.str, ctypes.bool], names=['id', 'name', 'isvalid'])`, and then `MyCTuple(1, "hello", True)` in the future. If this is possible, I think `CTuple` would be cool to have on PyPi!

Comment: After testing this @ead, I just tried with ctypes.Structure: `Tri7(ctypes.Structure): _fields_ = [("id", ctypes.c_int), ("name", ctypes.c_int), ("isvalid", ctypes.c_bool)]` (here I took the second param as int to avoid the char pointers complexity just for the test), but strangely it's not very good as well: 1.3 sec in my same test vs 0.3s for tuples.

Comment: @Basj that is not that surprising: while tuple and also CTuple are pure C-code at work. ctypes.Structure is mostly pure Python, so it will be somewhat slower (that is the reason for NameTuples being slower as well)

Comment: Thanks again for your great answer, and for the update, that confirms that recompilation is necessary for each new type of `CTuple` (I had a hope it would be possible with only one compilation once, and then only combinations of already compiled elements, but I think this is not possible ;)).

Comment: @Basj There is now `pip install cynamedtuple` available.

Comment: Waw @ead, this was a very interesting journey! Question, answers, improvements, and finally a package on PyPi, congrats!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to reverse it (store as struct of arrays) and access the values as `x['id'][1634]`. In other words, `x` is a dictionary with three keys and value for each key is a list. It will be space efficient.

Or you can use pandas dataframes. Dataframes are stored in a matrix form where the rows have numeric IDs and columns have labels (strings like 'name' etc.). For a dataframe `df`, `df.iloc[i]` points to the $i^th$ row and you can access the name in that row by `df.iloc[i].name` or `df.iloc[i]['name']`

Comment: `x['id'][K]` as proposed assumes `K` is an int from 0 to MAX. There was not such limitation In the original form `d[K].id`

Answer (score 1):

There is one another fast and compact way with the help of [recordclass](https://pypi.org/project/recordclass/) library:

```
pip3 install recordclass

import recordclass
TriDO = recordclass.make_dataclass("TriDO", 
           [('id', int), ('name', str), ('isvalid', bool)],
           fast_new=True)
```

Here are the values performance counters (linux, 64-bit, python3.9, recordclass >= 0.15):

`tuple:`

```
t0 = time.time()
d = {i: (i+1, 'hello', True) for i in range(1000000)}
print('%.3f s  %.1f MB' % (time.time()-t0,
      psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2))
0.235 s  259.1 MB
```

`dict:`

```
t0 = time.time()
d = {i: {'id':i+1, 'name':'hello', 'isvalid':True} for i in range(1000000)}
print('%.3f s  %.1f MB' % (time.time()-t0,
      psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2))
0.332 s  428.6 MB
```

`namedtuple:`

```
t0 = time.time()
d = {i: Tri(i+1, 'hello', True) for i in range(1000000)}
print('%.3f s  %.1f MB' % (time.time()-t0,
      psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2))
1.195 s  275.6 MB
```

'NamedTuple:'

```
t0 = time.time()
d = {i: Tri2(i+1, 'hello', True) for i in range(1000000)}
print('%.3f s  %.1f MB' % (time.time()-t0,
      psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2))
1.059 s  275.2 MB
```

`dataobject:`

```
t0 = time.time()
d = {i: TriDO(i+1, 'hello', True) for i in range(1000000)}
print('%.3f s  %.1f MB' % (time.time()-t0,
      psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2))
0.256 s  244.2 MB
```

Here more accurate timings:

```
%timeit d = {i:(i+1, 'hello', True) for i in range(1000000)} # tuple
162 ms ± 756 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit d = {i:{'id':i+1, 'name':'hello', 'isvalid':True} for i in range(1000000)} # dict
250 ms ± 2.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit d = {i:Tri(i+1,'hello',True) for i in range(1000000)} # namedtuple
318 ms ± 422 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit d = {i:Tri2(i+1,'hello',True) for i in range(1000000)} # NamedTuple
330 ms ± 5.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit d = {i:TriDO(i+1,'hello',True) for i in range(1000000)} # dataobject
188 ms ± 823 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep tuples and name your indices (2nd option below)

```
from enum import IntEnum

# int variable
ID, NAME, IS_VALID = 0, 1, 2

# IntEnum
class Index(IntEnum):
    ID = 0
    NAME = 1
    IS_VALID = 2
   

# Create tuples
d = {i: (i+1, 'hello', True) for i in range(int(1e6))}  

t0 = time.time()

# check data access performance
# uncomment only one of these 3 next lines:
# for i in range(len(d)): _ = d[i][0], d[i][1], d[i][2]
# for i in range(len(d)): _ = d[i][ID], d[i][NAME], d[i][IS_VALID]
for i in range(len(d)): _ = d[i][Index.ID], d[i][Index.NAME], d[i][Index.IS_VALID]

print('%.3f s' % (time.time()-t0))

"""
int           0.307 s
int variable  0.312 s
IntEnum       0.749 s
"""
```