# How to store multiple values received from socket in a structure in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, struct

I want to receive multiple messages from socket and I would like to store it in an structure like in `c++`. which will be used for further verification.

Here is my code:

```
def Receive(event,self):
   
    message = socket.recv(0.1)
```

`message` is an object which has attributes like `message.arbitration` , `message.timestamp`
I want to store the `message.timestamp` and other attributes from upcoming `recv` `socket` API in structure some how like this:

```
struct canmessage[0].timestamp[0]=message.timestamp
```

For example if I receive 100 messages,
I want to store the 100 messages in a structure in python.

How to implement this logic in python.

I have tried `list` and `dict` but nothing worked out.

Can anyone please help resolve this issue.

Comment: If `message` is already an object, couldn't you just store them in a `list` with `messages = []` `messages.append(message)`? And then access them with `messages[0].timestamp`? Although I doubt the `socket` itself would give you a `message` object without some abstraction involved.

Comment: How do you receive a tenth of a byte? 

Comment: Thanks for the comments , currently i m using this github.com/hardbyte/python-can/blob/develop/can/message.py class message is used to receive socket can message. I want to use this class and store in structure as like i have asked . Is that possible still ?

Answer (score 1):

The [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module can convert Python data to and from a byte stream suitable for transmission over a socket.  I can be used when you have a fixed format structure being transmitted or received.

In the following example, the sent or received packet follows the format of an network-ordered (big-endian) double followed by a 10-byte UTF-8-encoded string padded with null bytes if necessary.  The storage structure uses a `datetime` object and a Python Unicode `str`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import struct

class Message:

    def __init__(self, ts, arb):
        self.timestamp = ts
        self.arbitration = arb

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Message(timestamp={self.timestamp!r}, arbitration={self.arbitration!r})'

    def serialize(self):
        return struct.pack('!d10s', self.timestamp.timestamp(), self.arbitration.encode())

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, raw):
        ts, arb = struct.unpack('!d10s', raw)
        return Message(datetime.fromtimestamp(ts), arb.decode().rstrip('\x00'))

x = Message(datetime.now(), 'Yes?')
data = x.serialize()
print(data)
msg = Message.deserialize(data)
print(msg)
print(msg.timestamp.ctime(), msg.arbitration)
```

Output:

```
b'A\xd8D\xbb\x15R\xdb4Yes?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Message(timestamp=datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 10, 14, 15, 1, 294629), arbitration='Yes?')
Tue Aug 10 14:15:01 2021 Yes?
```

If you don't have a fixed format, JSON is a popular, readable format for transmitting data:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import json

class Message:

    def __init__(self, ts, arb):
        self.timestamp = ts
        self.arbitration = arb

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Message(timestamp={self.timestamp!r}, arbitration={self.arbitration!r})'

    def json(self):
        data = {'timestamp': self.timestamp.timestamp(), 'arbitration': self.arbitration}
        return json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode()

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, raw):
        data = json.loads(raw)
        return Message(datetime.fromtimestamp(data['timestamp']), data['arbitration'])

x = Message(datetime.now(), 'Yes?')
data = x.json()
print(data)
msg = Message.from_json(data)
print(msg)
print(msg.timestamp.ctime(), msg.arbitration)
```

Output:

```
b'{"timestamp": 1628630908.680338, "arbitration": "Yes?"}'
Message(timestamp=datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 10, 14, 28, 28, 680338), arbitration='Yes?')
Tue Aug 10 14:28:28 2021 Yes?
```

You can also use the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.htm#module-pickle) module which is meant for serializing/deserializing arbitrary Python objects, but note you have to trust the data received as unpickling arbitrary objects can be unsafe.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pickle

@dataclass
class Message:
    timestamp: datetime = datetime.now()
    arbitration: str = ''

data = pickle.dumps(Message(datetime.now(), 'Yes?'))
print(data)
msg = pickle.loads(data)
print(msg)
```

Output:

```
b'\x80\x04\x95j\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x07Message\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(\x8c\ttimestamp\x94\x8c\x08datetime\x94\x8c\x08datetime\x94\x93\x94C\n\x07\xe5\x08\n\x0e\x12#\x0e^\xa4\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x0barbitration\x94\x8c\x04Yes?\x94ub.'
Message(timestamp=datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 10, 14, 18, 35, 941732), arbitration='Yes?')
```

Transmitting and receiving the byte data packets is left as an exercise for the OP .  The `struct` format is fixed-sized (read 18 bytes from the socket).  `json` can use `socket.makefile` and `readline()` for reading a line at a time if transmitted in a single newline-terminated line.  `pickle` can read a pickled object(s) directly from a socket wrapped in a `makefile`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments , currently i m using this github.com/hardbyte/python-can/blob/develop/can/message.py class message is used to receive socket can message. I want to use this class and store in structure as like i have asked . Is that possible still ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988/c-like-structures-in-python) is helpful.
It is suggested to use the dataclass module to get struct like behaviour:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Message:
  timestamp: list = []
  arbitration: list = []

message = socket.recv(0.1)
can_messages = [Message()]
can_messages[0].timestamp.append(message.timestamp)
```

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments , currently i m using this https://github.com/hardbyte/python-can/blob/develop/can/message.py class message is used to receive socket can message. I want to use this class and store in structure as like i have asked . Is that possible still ?